# Check HTML page for particular table ID and element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, exists

Does jQuery have a method of determining if a particular table exists in a HTML document and `alert();` me whether it does or does not exist?

The particular tables' existence I'm looking for in the document is:

```
<table id="main_table"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    // after dom ready

    if($('table#main_table').length){
      alert('exists');
    }

})
```

Comment: Very admirable response time sir. :)

Answer (score 2):

at `domready` event just check

```
$(function() {
    if ($('#main_table').length) { ... /* element exists */ }

    /** 
     * or - without passing again through jQuery function -
     * if (document.getElementById('main_table')) { ... }
     */
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#check").click(function() {
         if($('table#main_table').length){
          alert('Table Exists');
        }
    });
});
```

​

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/3nVrZ/2/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input but I am unsure why you included a .click here.

Comment: it will show you alert after checking all the tables on page if required is available or not .Plz check the link given in answer